# Variable Substitution in .config file with Octopus Deploy 3

Tags: octopus-deploy, config-transformation

I am using Octopus Deploy v3 for my deployment.

Within my project I have defined a variable called data.folder

I am trying to use this variable to set the value in a transformation file that was deployed using a package

I have the following .config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" >
  <sitecore>
    <sc.variable name="dataFolder">
      <patch:attribute name="value">/Data</patch:attribute>
    </sc.variable>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

and the following .ci.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration 
     xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" 
     xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" 
     xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <sitecore>
    <sc.variable name="dataFolder" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Location="Match(name)" set:value="#{data.folder}" />
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Both of these files are located in folder App_Config\Include

As you can see I have set the variable in the transformation file to include the variable "{data.folder}"

Within Octopus, I have created a package deployment step, and have set the following features:

- Custom installation directory
- Configuration Variables
- Configuration transforms
- Substitute variables in files

Within the Substitute variables in files I have included the target files

App_Config\Include\Z_Project.#{Octopus.Environment.Id}.config

I believe that I have followed http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Substitute+Variables+in+Files correctly, however when the deployment runs. the variable in the .ci.config file is not being set.

I am sure I have made a very basic mistake, but I have no idea what I have done wrong

What do I need to get the transform file to use the variable from Octopus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've got the process correct in terms of the steps, the variables etc, but I don't think the transformation in the .ci.config file is correct after previewing a transformation.

It ends up like this

```
<sitecore>
  <sc.variable name="dataFolder" set:value="#{data.folder}"/>
</sitecore>
```

try using

```
<sitecore>
  <sc.variable name="dataFolder" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Location="Match(name)">
    <patch:attribute name="value">#{data.folder}</patch:attribute>
  </sc.variable>
</sitecore>
```

Running this through Slow Cheetah ([Visual Studio Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5)) performs the transformation correctly and provided everything else is setup in Octopus Deploy correctly this should get the value injected before the transformation happens.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately Octopus is still not replacing the variable with the data defined in the project. It is leaving it as #{data.folder}

Comment: And just to confirm there's an environment called ci and the data.folder variable in Octopus Deploy is not out of scope (scoped to another environment). I know there have also been issues with case sensitivity around environment names so it would be good to ensure they match (env = CI and file = CI.config). Is there anything in the logs around parsing the file for substitutions?

Comment: The variable is defined within the project. I have not set scope on the variable.  the Environment name is CI, all uppercase, and the transformation file, CI is also uppercase

Comment: WIth your and Octopus's Help, resolved the problem. I was using #{Octopus.Environment.Id} in the substitute variables, when I should have been using #{Octopus.Environment.Name}.  It turns out that the it was Id was returning "'Environments-1' Switching from .Id to .Name fixed the issue